# Generate create table sql with comment from migrations

Tags: python, django

I have searched Django's documentation, but I can't find any information about adding comments to the sql generated by Django's `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

Does any way can generate sql like this. Because my college insists he can know what the field mean for without read my code but using `SHOW CREATE TABLE` syntax. 
And he is working on another project that just need to read data from same database.

```
CREATE TABLE `gateway_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  /* Order id */
  `updated_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,  /* Latest update time of order */
  `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,  /* Created time of order */
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34848 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've [answered in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689190/624066):

- Ticket #13867 is now "superseded" by [#18468](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18468), which was *reopened* and is now **accepted** and waiting for patches.
- A partial solution, for PostgreSQL databases, is published at https://github.com/vanadium23/django-db-comments, as a post-migration hook Django app. Should not be hard to adjust it for MySQL databases.

Answer (score 3):

I am just looking for a method do such a thing in Django, but found Django didn't and won't have this feature:see: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13867

So just use the following command to output SQL generated by Django.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate app 0001 > app001.sql
```

And next, edit `app001.sql` add comment for SQL sentences as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `gateway_order` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Order id",
  `updated_datetime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT "Latest update time of order",
  `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT "Created time of order",
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34848 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then import the SQL to your database.

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p --database yourdb < app001.sql
```

and run

```
python manage.py migrate app --fake
```

to told Django, you've already create the SQL in database.

If a better method found, please told me.