# django model field comment in database

Tags: django

this is the model class(django version 2.0)

```
class Host(models.Model):
    host_id=models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    host_label=models.CharField(verbose_name="linux_host_label",max_length=255)
```

the table structrue in database

```
mysql> show create table dashboard_host;
| dashboard_host | CREATE TABLE `dashboard_host` (
  `host_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `host_label` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

but how to do in the model class to get like this

```
mysql> show create table dashboard_host;
| dashboard_host | CREATE TABLE `dashboard_host` (
  `host_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '主机id',
  `host_label` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '主机标签',
  PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+----------------+-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well there is no such way in django from the model directly. you can check the ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24638

but you can do one thing,

first `makemigrations your app` and then edit the migration file and place

```
  CREATE TABLE `dashboard_host` (
  `host_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT '主机id',
  `host_label` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '主机标签',
  PRIMARY KEY (`host_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

inplace of the sql query automatically generated by django

and then `migrate`

Comment: That ticket is for an entirely different class of comments. Relevant tickets are https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13867 and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18468

Answer (score 1):

Looks like currently you can't, at least not in Django. I was able to find 2 similar request tickets in Django:

[#13867 Feature request: Comments in Django models saved to database schema](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13867)

Opened 9 years ago and dismissed as `wontfix` an year later, with rationale along the lines of *"it doesn't have a good usefulness/noise ratio. The ORM doesn't aim at providing a Python interface for every feature of the supported database engine"*

[#18468 Add the ability to define comments in table / columns](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18468)

Opened 7 years ago, marked as a duplicate of the above, end of story until... plot twist! **Reopened** on 2018-03, went trough discussion on mailing list, and now marked as **Accepted**. Original rejecter said *"I think we could implement that feature. (Yes I changed my mind from six years ago when I wontfix'd the ticket.)"*

So now this only requires an implementation / patch / PR , which hasn't been done yet (but anyone can contribute!)

The ticket submitter started making a patch, and created a Django App that fixes the problem for Fields (using `verbose_name` and `help_text` attributes) on PostgreSQL backends. You're using MySQL, but it might be trivial to adapt it:

https://github.com/vanadium23/django-db-comments

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Django 4.2 you can use *[`Field.db_comment` and `Meta.db_table_comment` options to create comments on columns and tables respectively](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#comments-on-columns-and-tables)*.

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(db_comment="Poll question")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        db_comment="Date and time when the question was published",
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table_comment = "Poll questions"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use python package： https://pypi.org/project/django-comment-migrate/,
It has two characteristics:

1. Automatic migration model help_text to comment
2. Provide a command to migrate the comment of the specified app
   Examples